# unexpected T_String when adding "get_the_excerpt" to single.php

Tags: php

When I add

```
<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt() ?>
```

to the single page php code below, I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 10"

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="post"><?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class('margin') ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<div class="casestudy"><a class="anchor-hover">
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?>
    <span class="details">
        <p class="desc"><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt() ?>
</p>
</span>
</a>
<?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

My functions.php file originally did not have

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
```

so I added that but I still get the error. What am I missing here? Have I taken it out of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you forgot the `;` at the end there.

I'm also curious as to why you are simply setting the variable in a `<p>` instead of maybe `echo`ing it?

Comment: as for why I haven't echoed it, I'm moving styling that was added to a post into a custom post type so I can replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a semi-colon :) simple errors are the worst right?